# IOS 8 Webapp start up images

Tags: ios, web-applications, homescreen

For the life of me I can't get the IOS webapp startup images to work for me when opening my webapp from the homescreen. Here is the code I have in my head tag. Please help.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>AXIS</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="AXIS">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimul-ui=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/Content/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/Content/images/apple-touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/Content/images/apple-touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/Content/images/apple-touch-icon-iphone-retina-display.png" />
<link href="/Content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-retina.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<link href="/Content/images/apple-touch-startup-image-non-retina.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Comment: Maybe http://taylor.fausak.me/2015/01/27/ios-8-web-apps/ helps?